# Get .apk file of an installed application on a android device through java code

Tags: android

Is it possible to generate an .apk file for an application already installed on a android device using java code ?

Comment: then how does apps like app-share, share it work. bcoz they do transfer apk files from one device to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the android apk are stored in the following path:

```
/data/app
```

The permissions of this dir is `drwxrwx--x`

The permission if the files(apk's) inside this folder are `-rw-r--r--`

Since there is read permission for `others`, so you will be able to read the files if you know the names of the apk's. You can do that by the means of simple java File IO operations.

Comment: so, what can i help u with.

Comment: that i'll do once i test this thing

Comment: The apks do exist at the path u have given. I was able to view apks but only for emulator through adb. On a non-rooted device i got permission denied while trying to view the files inside /data/app folder. Still need to check through java code. Thanks..!!!

Comment: you will not be able to list the files because of `--x` permission. You need `r--` permission for that. Which means you can read the contents of the files but can not see list of files.